# Raster calculator: could not create destination file

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator

I am trying to create a curve number distribution using a raster calculator using the code shown in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uk0cz.png). However, I was getting the error shown in [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvZSA.png). I am using QGIS 3.28.15 version to do the process.

[image: Raster Calculator Code]
[image: Raster Calculator Error]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full path to the output raster you are trying to write to.